# parsing the file

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have the file that has content like this per line

```
3021e69d9d2569db27ce7b74ccaa98496007de09a1f4b94e45f48203d8727ac6 test.com [05/Jul/2011:07:28:57 +0000] 126.97.98.19 3021e69d9d2569db27ce7b74ccaa98496007de09a1f4b94e45f48203d8727ac6 70706DF22A809F33 REST.GET.OBJECT 1as21/foldera/file.png "GET //folder/test.php?AWSAccessKeyId=45dsgrg$5f&Expires=1310388787&Signature=Yehn847BhdsaiuernYmjne= HTTP/1.1" 206 - 47972352 209316737 54194091 7 "http://test.info/?url=http://ns.in/54325" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1" -
```

So i used the following code to parse

```
$file_handle = fopen($filename, "r");
            while (!feof($file_handle)) {
              $data = fgets($file_handle);
              $test = explode(" ",$data);
                      ......
```

The problem is that I am dividing the line with spaces to get to this 206. However, it makes more divisions than necessary. Is there away to do it better? Is there a space character that I should look for that will not count anything in " ..." as a space? As it counts "GET //  even though its clearly enclosed in " "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use PHP [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php). It was designed for this scenario. This question has been answered in different ways on Stack Overflow. Nonetheless I did a quick script that does this for you. I think it can be improved in a few ways.

It uses 2 passive groups to evaluate the input string with the last expression being the one that splits the string with a space delimiter.

[preg_split example script on Gist](https://gist.github.com/1080107)

```
###     
$str = '3021e69d9d2569db27ce7b74ccaa98496007de09a1f4b94e45f48203d8727ac6 test.com [05/Jul/2011:07:28:57 +0000] 126.97.98.19 3021e69d9d2569db27ce7b74ccaa98496007de09a1f4b94e45f48203d8727ac6 70706DF22A809F33 REST.GET.OBJECT 1as21/foldera/file.png "GET //folder/test.php?AWSAccessKeyId=45dsgrg$5f&Expires=1310388787&Signature=Yehn847BhdsaiuernYmjne= HTTP/1.1" 206 - 47972352 209316737 54194091 7 "http://test.info/?url=http://ns.in/54325" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1" -';


$regex = <<<REG
 /"((?:[^"]*|)++)\"
 |\[((?:[^\]]*|)++)\]
 |[\s]
/x
REG;

$out = preg_split($regex,$str,0,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE );

var_dump($out);
###
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use regular expression to parse your data. It's a bit tricky at first, but does wonderful job.

[preg_match — Perform a regular expression match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)